# Algebra problem about spam and polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How do you know when a set of polynomials span r2
For example, P1 = x+ 5x^2+x^3
 and P2 is the same.
What constitutes a set to be in the span or a specific space?

Comment: Hint: what does $B$ do to an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: Please post a picture showing the entire problem. Thanks! :-)

Comment: B divides the eigenvector of A by beta, but I don't understand how to go about proving this. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This is the entire problem, it just looks distorted.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what I understand of the problem, this would be my thought process:
$$\textbf{[A]}\vec x=\lambda\vec x$$
Above is the definition of an eigenvector and associated eigenvalue. The $\lambda$ in this case corresponds to the $\lambda$ in the problem.
$$\frac{1}{\beta}\textbf{[A]}\vec x=\frac{1}{\beta}\lambda\vec x$$
Above we multiplied both sides by $\frac{1}{beta}$.
$$\frac{\textbf{[A]}\vec x}{\beta}=\frac{\lambda\vec x}{\beta}$$
$$\frac{\textbf{[A]}}{\beta}\vec x=\frac{\lambda}{\beta}\vec x$$
Factoring happens, since we are using a scalar.
$$\textbf{[B]}\vec x=\frac{\lambda}{\beta}\vec x$$
So the new eigenvalue is $\frac{\lambda}{\beta}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, there is an eigenvector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v$.

Now, using the same eigenvector $v$, we have $Bv = \dfrac{A}{\beta}v = \dfrac{Av}{\beta} = \dfrac{\lambda v}{\beta}$ (since $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$), and this is equal to $\dfrac{\lambda}{\beta}v$.  So, we found that $Bv = \dfrac{\lambda}{\beta}v$, which shows that $\dfrac{\lambda}{\beta}$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$ (the same eigenvector that was for eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$!).